# iOS7 SplitviewController embedded in ContainerView does not rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I am pretty new to iOS and Objective-C but I am trying to create an iPad app with a vertical tab bar down the left hand side and a split view controller taking up the rest of the screen. To achieve this I have put two container views on a page then embedded the splitview controller in the right container.

Here is my story board:

[image]

This works fine in landscape, however when I rotate to portrait the split view controller does not rotate as normal and this messes up the whole layout.

Here is what it looks like in landscape, as expected:
[image]

Here is what it looks like in portrait:
[image]

I've tried various things like manually forwarding willHideViewController and willShowViewController from the container to the splitview controller...

Is there something I'm missing? Or a better way to achieve the layout I'd like?

Comment: `UISplitViewController` is intended to be used as a root view controller only.  There might be a way to get this to work, but Apple certainly doesn't want you using `UISplitViewController` as anything other than a root view controller.

Comment: Yeah I have seen this. I guess I'm hoping there is a way to make it work?

Comment: How did you showing WHOLE SPLIT VIEW-CONTROLLER in the RIGHT Container View ? Please share the steps @JimmyP

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, in portrait mode the master view controller is transferred to a popover, which is normally placed off-screen to the left of the detail view controller. In your case, you can see it is also to the left, but this is the incorrect behavior for your case.

Implement the split view controller's delegate protocol, specifically `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:` and return `NO` for any orientation.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but which class needs to implement the protocol? ContainerViewController?

Comment: @JimmyP Depends how you have set up your logic. It could be the container, it could be the master, it could be the detail. I've seen all configurations, and they are valid. Since your split view configuration seems to be static, the container could be a good place.